# Access Query By Month Day Ignore Year and Group By Year

Tags: date, ms-access

So I currently have a 3 table relationship setup as follows:

APN (pk)

APN
Address

Address
Usage
Date
Period (year)

I am attempting to sum the Usage field by APN and group Usage totals (per APN)  by the Period. I cant figure out how to reference the Date range in a query while ignoring the year, but also grouping the records by the year so they dont aggregate different years within the month range (3/1 to 4/31)

Answer (score 0):

Group by month and year. Something like this:

```
Select
    APN,
    Year([YourDateField]),
    Month([YourDateField]),
    Sum(Usage) As TotalUsage
From
    YourTable 
    <insert inner joins as needed>
Group By
    APN,
    Year([YourDateField]),
    Month([YourDateField])
```